# Get the result of two compared list and change an attribut in list deponding on the result using LINQ

Tags: c#, wpf, list, linq

I have two lists of objects, let's suppose that the first is called Department and the second is called Student.

```
public class Student {

   public int Id {get; set; }

   public string Name {get; set; }

   public bool IsActive {get; set; }
  
   public int DepId {get;set;} 
}


 public class Department {

       public int DepId {get; set; }

       public string DepName {get; set; }
    }
```

**Remarks**: The list of users is filled with many objects ( more than 150 000 items ).

For that reason, I've used `Task.Run()`

```
 private async Task UpdateMyGrid()
    {
       departments = ....; // list of departments 
       students = ..... ;  // list of students
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            var results = students.Where(x => departments.Any(y => y.DepId== x.DepId));

            foreach (var s in students)
            {
                if (results.ToList().Exists(p => p.DepId== s.DepId))
                {
                    s.IsEnabled = false;
                }
            }
            GridViewStudent.ItemsSource = null;
            GridViewStudent.ItemsSource = students;
        });
    }
```

I would like to compare two lists of users and departments and get the results between them and then set the attribute `IsActive` to false .

Example :

```
List students: {1,"John",True,001} , {2,"Mariah",True,003},{3,"Karima",True,002},{4,"Jenny",True,004}

List departments: {001,"Science"} , {002,"Culture"}
```

**The expected result:**

```
 Results will be => {1,"John",True,001},{3,"Karima",True,002}

 Students will be => {1,"John",False,001} , {2,"Mariah",True,003},
{3,"Karima",False,002},{4,"Jenny",True,004}
```

What can I do to make the above code works?

Comment: But without using it my UI was blocked

Comment: What is the actual problem? Do you have expected input/output?

Comment: I will give an example .

Comment: See the update now.

Comment: I don't get the logic - what is the logic between expected and actual? Are you trying to modify student active status based on if the department exists? Do you want to output results or students?

Comment: I can't find any pattern between input students and output students - ignore results, what are you trying to do to students based on the department?

Can you please run through it with one thorough example?

Comment: @csharp_devloper31: Why is "John" `true` in results but false in students...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
private async Task UpdateMyGrid()
{
    
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        
        foreach (var s in students)
        {
            if (departments.Exists(p => p.DepId == s.DepId))
            {
                s.IsActive= true;
            }else s.IsActive=false;
        }
        GridViewStudent.ItemsSource = null;
        GridViewStudent.ItemsSource = students;
    });
}
```

output

```
    1   John    True    1
    2   Mariah  False   3
    3   Karima  True    2
    4   Jenny   False   4
```

or if you for some reason are expecting on the contrary you can use this, and it is using TPL library too

```
await Task.Run(() =>
    {

        Parallel.ForEach(students, s =>
           {
               if (departments.Exists(p => p.DepId == s.DepId))
            {
                s.IsActive= false;
            }else s.IsActive=true;
        });
```

output

```
    1   John    False   1
    2   Mariah  True    3
    3   Karima  False   2
    4   Jenny   True    4
```

but IMHO the fastest way would be if you make a left join students and departments in data base server already

```
var students =  await (from s in context.students
                join d in context.departments on s.DepId equals d.DepId into gj
                     from d in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     select new Student
                 {
                     Id=s.Id,
                     Name=s.Name,
                     DepId=s.DepId,
                     DepExist= d==null?false: true,
                } ).ToListAsync();

    Parallel.ForEach(students, s =>
           {
               s.IsActive = s.DepExist;
            });
```

in this case you need to add one more property to student

```
[NotMapped]
public bool DepExist { get; set; }
```

Comment: OP has said expected output is `{1,"John",False,001} , {2,"Mariah",True,003},
{3,"Karima",False,002},{4,"Jenny",True,004}` ?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary Thanks, I put 2 variants since it is very confusing. I thought if a department exists then a student is active

Comment: Same here, no worries - waiting on OP

Comment: Yes, the students list depend on the departments. I will search if the student in students exists in a department list , isActive will be `False`

Comment: Both solutions, yours and the solution of @Yaseen works for me, I mean the solution of Parallel, but I didn't have any idea about this functionality, could you please explain it or give some tutorials to understand the concept

Comment: @csharp_devloper31 It is hard to explain it in two words. You can read this tutorial for example https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/parallel-foreach-method-csharp/

Comment: @csharp_developer31  You are welcome. You can try Parallel Foreach async  as well https://medium.com/@alex.puiu/parallel-foreach-async-in-c-36756f8ebe62

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to increase performace.
For that you can use Parallel.For instead of foreach loop since you have lot of objects.

```cs
            Parallel.ForEach(students, s =>
            {
               if (results.ToList().Exists(p => p.DepId== s.DepId))
                {
                    s.IsActive  = false;
                }
            });
```

It is available in System.Threading.Tasks;

Comment: Thanks , but the question is not about performance please read my question again.

Answer (score 0):

Store the department ids in a `HashSet<int>`:

```
var hashSet = new HashSet<int>(departments.Select(x => x.DepId));
```

...and iterate through the students:

```
var results = new List<Student>();
foreach (var student in students)
{ 
    if (hashSet.Contains(student.DepId)
    {
        results.Add(student);
        student.IsActive = false;
    } 
}
```

Since you only have one `Student` object per student, the `IsActive` property cannot be `true` on one collection and `false` in another. If you want two different objects, you should clone the original one.